# Word 365 Image Captions

Tags: microsoft-word, caption

I have a single column Word 365 document, into which I would like to insert a number of full-column (or very nearly so) figures with captions, under the following constraints:

- Figures should be with text wrapping, top and bottom, moveable with text
- Captions should NOT be 'shapes'
- Captions should be above the images
- Captions should move with the images and remain on the same page (i.e., "Keep with next")

No matter what I do, Word cannot seem to meet all these constraints.  If I make a caption for an image with text wrapping, the caption is automatically made as a shape.  If I make a caption for an in-line image, the caption is not a shape, and I can convert the image back to text wrapping.  That meets the first three constraints.

But the caption does not move with the image, even when 'Keep with next' is applied.

Effectively 'Keep with next' seems fundamentally broken/useless in this context.  I have to group the image and the caption, which can only be done when the caption is a 'shape' which leads to excess whitespace under the

What am I missing?  How can I keep a non-shape caption and a wrapped image co-located on the page?  This is making this document incredibly frustrating to edit.

(Note:  Embedding the caption into the figure is both infeasible-- this will be a 100+ page document with dozens of images some of which may be repositioned or deleted during editing-- and specifically disallowed by the recipient with no flexibility in this matter *at all.*  It is not even clear if 'grouping' is allowed, either.)

Comment: Actually, even grouping them does not work right.  Is there no way to specify that the captions stick to the figures/images like any sensible person would want them to do?

Comment: See my writing on moving figures and captions together. https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/complex_documents.htm#MovingFigureCaption --- Both must either be in-line-with text or floating (i.e. the Caption must be in a Text Box).